# UITableView Index and Sections

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I have question. What do I have to do to add an Index and sections to my tableView? I am using Core Data. I have something like this:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

     if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
         return _fetchedResultsController;
     }

     NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
     AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
     NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
     NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Team" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
     [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
     [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

     NSString *sectionKey = nil;

     NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
     NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"number" ascending:YES];
     NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor1, sortDescriptor2, nil];
     [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
     sectionKey = @"name";


     _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:sectionKey cacheName:@"Team"];
     _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

     return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Comment: Couldn't understand what you are intending to do based on the above posted code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your NSFetchedResultsController have sections with objects on it, you just haver to asign the datasource of your table view to your class and do this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if ([[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count] > 0) {
        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
        return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
    } else
        return 0;
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = <#Get the cell#>;
    NSManagedObject *managedObject = [<#Fetched results controller#> objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell with data from the managed object.
    return cell;

}



- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section { 
    if ([[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count] > 0) {
        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[<#Fetched results controller#> sections] objectAtIndex:section];
        return [sectionInfo name];
    } else
        return nil;
}


- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [<#Fetched results controller#> sectionIndexTitles];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    return [self.fetchedResultsController sectionForSectionIndexTitle:title atIndex:index];
}
```

This is taken from:

[NSFetchedResulstController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: It worked perfectly! But theres a problem... The title of each section it's not the first letter of name but the whole name! how can I fix this?

Comment: Just change the titleForHeaderInSection method to return only the first letter of the string. Please accept the answer if it helped!